# how to mask URL with desired words instead of lengthy domain name?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

Hi guys here i am working on a new web project(e-commerce website) in which whole project is done in java and that to only in `jsp's` even java code is written in `jsp` .Action pages are written in jsps instead of servlets and database connectivity in simple `.java` files.now my boss asks me to get a customized url in the browser.any help will be thankful.

**EXAMPLE:**

https://www.buzzmeal.com/?register=login&success=true&name=xxx&address=xxx.
this is the url which i am getting at present what i need is https://www.buzzmeal.com/regester. i tried servlet url redirection but in that way i should create servlet for each of the jsp.can any busy suggest me best way to mask a url using java.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess file. Here is a small tutorial with examples:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049